# iOS TableView Constraints doesn’t work

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

**Hi. I’m already tried to find some info about it at Goodle, but nothing could help me.**
I’m swift beginner. Help me, please.

I want to auto layout this `TableViewCell` in `TableViewController`.

[image: TableViewController]

Now it’s look fine in IB, Preview and Simulator, but only on this screen size, sure.

Then I added by 5 constrains, as I saw at one StackOverflow answer, to each of subview of Cell like this:

[image]

and now, when I run project is look crashed:

[image]

**WHY** ?

Comment: are you also setting your cell height programmatically?

Comment: @ShamasS no, just in IB

Comment: instead of adding constraint on subviews , add UIView as container view and add subviews in it and apply suggested constraint on it.On last add constraint on UIView

Comment: Are you using stackview?

Comment: @PGDev no, I dislike this method now, I just learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIStackView` for such kind of nested views. It just reduces the number of constraints required to be applied by the developer.

**Example:**

**1. UITableViewDataSource**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
}
```

**2. Storyboard: View Hierarchy and Constraints:**

[image]

**3. Output:**

[image]

I haven't used the `height/estimatedHeight` `UITableViewDelegate` methods. It will be automatically calculated by the cell `(if the constraints are right and the cell is able to calculate its own height)`.

Comment: Interesting solution! Thanks!

Comment: Sure..accept the answer if it worked..

Answer (score -1):

If you added these 5 constraints to **each** subview of your cell, then it's incorrect. Moreover, contentView is also a subview of the cell and you're modifying its width - thus showing a reduced width. Plus, each of the subviews (that shouldn't include the contentView) should have different constraints.

You can also let Xcode determine estimate the height of the cell automatically based on your constraints using **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**.